# Python constants declaration

Tags: python, constants

if I declare a const class which are contains variables:

for example

```
class const:
    MASTER_CLIENT_CONNECTED = 0
    CLIENT_CONNECTED = 1        
    GET_SERVER_QUEUE = 9998    
    ERROR = 9999
```

is there any way to reach this variable(constants) without creating a new class.

like this:

```
import const
const.MASTER_CLIENT_CONNECTED
```

or

```
import const
if(i==MASTER_CLIENT_CONNECTED):
```

Comment: Do you mean "creating a new class" or do you mean "instantiating an instance of a class"?

Comment: Apparently yes: http://codepad.org/hgv0iH92 (I assumed you mean *new instance*) These things are easy to try yourself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, instead of putting them in a class put them directly into your module (name the file e.g. `const.py` so the module name is `const`). Using a class for this is pretty much abusing classes for namespacing - and Python has [packages/modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) for this purpose.

Then you could even use `from const import *` to import all globals from this module if you don't want to write `const.` in front of everything. However note that this is usually discouraged as it potentially imports lots of things into the global namespace - if you just need one or two constants `from const import ABC, DEF` etc. would be fine though.

Comment: I want to use in other classes, share this constant values.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you need a class for that? You can use something like this:

In constant.py write:

```
MASTER_CLIENT_CONNECTED = 0
CLIENT_CONNECTED = 1        
GET_SERVER_QUEUE = 9998    
ERROR = 9999
```

Then access it as:

```
import constant
print constant.MASTER_CLIENT_CONNECTED
print constant.CLIENT_CONNECTED 
print constant.GET_SERVER_QUEUE 
print constant.GET_SERVER_QUEUE
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above solutions the only drawback is that you can accidentally modify the variables in the const.py file -

```
#const.py
var_a = 1

#app.py
import const
print(const.var)
const.var = 2
print(const.var)

#output
1
2
```

This maybe a hacky solution, but to prevent modification of any constant variable, you can add them to a class with only getter methods.

```
#const.py
class Constants:
    @classmethod
    get_vara(cls):
        return 1


#app.py
from const import Constants
print(Constants.get_vara())

#output
1
```

I know that this method may crowd up the const.py file, but this is the only solution I know which in true definition exemplifies immutability.